# Merge data into single Dictionary after cross join of two list in c#

Tags: c#, linq, cross-join

[image]I have two Lists of Dictionary and I am applying LINQ query to get cross join.

```
var result= list1.SelectMany(x=> list2,(x,y)=> new {x,y});
```

Now the result has all records but both x and y are separated but I want both Dictionaries in a single row without x and y, also Dictionary in tables are dynamic so it may have any key and values.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hi Rushi, can you provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that we can help you in proper direction

Comment: An easier way to upload better quality pictures of your screen: Click start. Type SNIP. Launch Snipping Tool. Use it to capture a region (click new.. drag..). Press Ctrl C. Switch to SO question edit box. Press Ctrl V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you mean you want your output "row" to be a single dictionary containing all of x and all of y. It could be like:

```
var result= list1.SelectMany(
  x=> list2,
  (x,y) => new Dictionary<WhateverType,YouHave>(x.Concat(Y))
);
```

It takes all of the `KeyValuePair<WhateverTypr,YouHave>` in x and y and makes an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<WhateverType,YouHave>>` from them, then makes a new Dictionary that contains all those keyvaluepairs

The types of the dictionary will need to be consistent; you can't have x be a `Dictionary<string,int>` and y be a `Dictionary<int,string>` for example